# How to define a constant in R

Tags: r, constants

Let me describe the problem setting. The function I am depicting is a probability function and upon integration it's value would have to be equal to 1. So I will be dividing the result of the integration by 1 to give the value of C. So I can't assign value to C.

Have a look at the below code and error message -

```
> f <- function(x) (C*x*(exp(-x)))
> z=integrate(f, lower = 0, upper=Inf)
Error in C * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

How am I supposed to define `C` here ?

---

Second Question- Can somebody figure what's wrong with value of `z`?

```
> f <- function(x) (x*(exp(-x)))
> z=integrate(f, lower = 0, upper=Inf)
> z
1 with absolute error < 6.4e-06
> 1/z
Error in 1/z : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Comment: can you not simply add `C` as a parameter to your function?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting the below modification -
f <- function(x,C) (C*x*(exp(-x)))
I don't agree with it completely, because the function is dependent on value of x not of C.

Comment: right...but if C is a parameter you need to pass in to your function, you've got to define it somewhere...the alternative would be to define `C` in your global environment and R will probably find it...but that's not really a good practice...you'd then change your `integrate` call to `integrate(f, lower = 0, upper=Inf, C = 2)` where 2 was the arbitrary number i picked.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But that does not look ideal. I can very well define "C=2" before defining the function. 
Let me describe the problem setting below.
The function i am depicting is a probability function and upon integration it's value would have to be equal to 1. So I will be dividing the result of the integration by 1 to give the value of C. So I can't assign value to C .

Comment: i clearly don't understand your problem and fear it may not be clear to others. When you say "define a constant", I interpret that to mean "I have a single value that I know I need to define". What you said above does not seem to fit that paradigm...maybe others can help.

Comment: I understand ..may be 'Constant' is not right word here. I am new to R, so difficulty with terminologies. But as you understand the problem setting, can you tell me what should be the keyword for such a query? I will try to look through the older posts with the keyword. I tried to search with keyword 'constant' and didn't get any relevant posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `C = 1` for when you compute the integral of the function. For that, you can make it an optional argument to your function with a default value:

```
f <- function(x, C = 1) C * x * exp(-x)
```

Then, compute:

```
z <- integrate(f, lower = 0, upper = Inf)
```

For the integral to be `1` with the *real* value for `C`, you need `C * z == 1`, i.e.:

```
C <- 1 / z$value
C
# [1] 1
```

As it turns out, the integral `z` is already equal to `1` so picking `C = 1` was a lucky choice. You have nothing to do and you can just start using `f` as-is. Had it not been the case, I would have suggested to redefine `f`:

```
f_final <- function(x) f(x, C = 1 / z$value)
```

(Regarding your second question, you just had to look at the documentation for `?integrate` and refer to the "Value" section.)